# slf4j dependency not found

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, slf4j, circular-dependency

When trying to deploy my web application, It fails due to logging errors such as the following:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)

I've google'd this error and it seems to be an issue with one of my dependencies pulling in a wrong version, but I can't find where this is happening. I have included the dependency tree output:

[image]

Any Ideas?

EDIT: Added output of mvn dependency:resolve:

```
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-jsp:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
[INFO]    org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO]    mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.15:compile
[INFO]    commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.social:spring-social-web:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.12:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO]    commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO]    junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO]    org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO]    commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-servlet:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO]    org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO]    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO]    javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO]    javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:3.1.0.RC3:compile
[INFO]    commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.tiles:tiles-template:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO]    org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.10.Final:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.tiles:tiles-autotag-core-runtime:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO]    org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.tiles:tiles-api:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO]    aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:3.0.1:compile
```

Comment: Why are you mentioning log4j? There's nothing about it in your error message. Also, please post the *entire* output of `mvn dependency:resolve`, as text.

Comment: Log4j is the Slf4j implementation I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all slf4j-packages (slf4j-api, slf4j-log4j12, jcl-over-slf4j) are of the same version. Especially mismatches in the minor version (between the api and the jcl-bridge) are problematic and should be avoided. Since you use maven, it shouldn't be difficult to explicitly declare the same specific version for all those packages.

See also here: http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch